# C# How to Pass Anon Class by Reference

Tags: c#

With VB.net, I'm able to pass an anonymous class by reference and the method is able to modify the class.
Yes, I know it's using Reflection but I need the dynamic capability more than I need speed.

[VB DotNetFiddle:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JLxRPA)

```
Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim oAnon = New With {.A = "Coding", .B = "in", .C = "VB"}
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + oAnon.ToString())
        MyFunction(oAnon)
        Console.WriteLine("After: " + oAnon.ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Sub MyFunction(ByRef o as Object)
        For Each p As Reflection.PropertyInfo In o.GetType().GetProperties()
            If p.CanRead Then
                If p.Name = "A" Then p.SetValue(o, "Moving", Nothing)
                If p.Name = "B" Then p.SetValue(o, "to", Nothing)
                If p.Name = "C" Then p.SetValue(o, "C#", Nothing)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

I've not been able to get similar C# code to work.
[C# DotNetFiddle:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WXlCqm)

```
public static class Module1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var oAnon = new
        {
        A = "Coding", B = "in", C = "VB"
        }

        ;
        Object o = (object)oAnon;
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + oAnon.ToString());
        MyFunction(ref o); // Unable to Cast oAnon to Object Inline
        Console.WriteLine("After: " + oAnon.ToString());
    }

    public static void MyFunction(ref object o)
    {
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in o.GetType().GetProperties())
            if (p.CanRead)
            {
                if (p.Name == "A")
                    p.SetValue(o, "Moving", null);
                if (p.Name == "B")
                    p.SetValue(o, "to", null);
                if (p.Name == "C")
                    p.SetValue(o, "C#", null);
            }
    }
}
```

The method must be an object because there are ~500 different classes that are passed to this one method.

Here's the desired output:

```
Before: { A = Coding, B = in, C = VB }
After: { A = Moving, B = to, C = C# }
```

Q. What changes are necessary in the C# code to make it perform identically to the VB code?

Comment: What error are you getting? And at what line?

Comment: Note that anonymous types are _already_ reference types, so you don't need the `ref` keyword if you don't want to change the actual reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What changes are necessary in the C# code to make it perform identically to the VB code?

You can't. Anonymous types are immutable in C# - in VB they are mutable by default but properties can be made immutable by using the `Key` modifier.

If you need a mutable anonymous type then you're doing it wrong. Use a dictionary or a strong type instead. Or return a new instance rather then mutating the passed-in instance.

Comment: Wow, didn't know yet that anonymous objects are immutable, but true apparently

Comment: Yep. The reason is so that they can reliably be be hashed when doing things like joins and grouping. Modifying objects that are used as hash table keys can be problematic.

Comment: Thank you, @DStanley!  I removed the ref keywords (a misunderstanding) and passed an empty dictionary to return the results. [C# DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FNeG59)